# activemq consumer enumeration

Tags: .net, activemq-classic, nms

Is it possible to use an activemq consumer (in .NET) like this?

foreach (var msg in consumer) {

// process message

}

such that the enumeration loop stops, without consuming CPU, until a message is available? Effectively it would be an infinite loop unless something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform a synchronous consume to achieve something like this with a while loop:

```
IMessage message = null;
while((message = consumer.Receive()) != null)
{
    //... process the message.
}
```

-Tim www.fusesource.com